# Возможно ли в методе-расширении изменить объект, к которому и применяется расширение? (C#)

Tags: c#, методы, extension, расширения

Добрый день, товарищи! 
Предположим, есть у нас некоторый статический метод-расширение вида:

```
public static string[] Method(this string[] Arr) 
{ 
Некоторые действия со входным массивом...; 
return Arr; 
}
```

Моя проблема заключается в следующем: возможно ли как-то изменить первоначально передаваемый массив Arr, чтобы мне не пришлось прописывать

```
Arr = Arr.Method();
```

А было достаточно лишь

```
Arr.Method();
```

Просто с ключевым словом this отказывается работать большинство других ключевых слов, которые бы могли этому поспособствовать! Что можно было бы придумать в данной ситуации?

Comment: Что значит "изменить"? Массивы - это ссылочный тип, вы можете менять его без всяких ref/out (если тип мутабельный by design). Другое дело, если вы хотите присвоить переменной другое значение, то семантически верно именно переприсваивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С расширениями работают точно так же, как и с простыми статическими методами. Просто обрабатывайте ваш `Arr` внутри расширения `Method()`. Вы же передаете ссылочный тип в расширение.

В таком случае правильней будет сделать расширение с `void` возвращаемым типом.

PS. В данном случае я бы посоветовал использовать `ICollection<string>` вместо `string[]`.

Для "разрешения" добавления элемента можно привести коллекцию к списку с помощью [`IEnumerable.ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var values = new string[]{ "val1", "val2" };
var valueCollection = values.ToList();
valueCollection.AddItem();
```

В таком случае расширение станет примерно таким:

```
public static void AddItem(this IList<string> target)
{
    target.Add("another item");
}
```

[Протестить!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f6hiRM)

Comment: В том все и веселье, что я сначала пытался сделать void. В конце я присваивал переданному массиву новое значение. Но, увы, это никак не отражалось на изначальном массиве

Comment: @Kir_Antipov ваше "в конце" переписывает ссылку на входящий массив на результирующий. Вы должны работать со входящим массивом как будто у вас статический метод

Comment: @vitidev, doh. Верно. А как можнорасширить существующий массив без перезаписи его ссылки?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov массив имеет конечный размер и расширить себя без создания нового массива не даст. Поэтому придется создать новый и вернуть его. Любое присваивание просто создаст новую ссылку, про которую никто извне  знать не будет.

Comment: @vitidev, а жаль. Спасибо!

Comment: @Kir_Antipov обновился.